# Clojure / Ring: Response map is nil when adding session key

Tags: clojure, ring

I want to update a session key on /callback upon logging in. Here's the handler:

```
(defn callback [{session :session :as request}]
  (let [id (:id (get-current-users-profile))
        updated-session (assoc session :identity id)]
    {:status 200
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
     :body (loading-page)
     :session updated-session}))
```

As long as the session key-value pair is present in the response map, I get a 500 "Response map is nil" response.

Is there something I'm doing wrongly here?

By the way, I can still update the session map (with no errors) on my /logout route by doing the following:

```
(defn logout [{session :session}]
  (-> (resp/redirect "/")
      (assoc :session {})))
```

And here's what calls both `callback` and `logout`:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] index)
  (GET "/login" [] login)
  (GET "/callback" [] callback)
  (GET "/logout" [] logout))
```

Comment: Insufficient information to diagnose. The `callback` function looks fine in isolation, but how are you calling these?

Comment: I just added more information to the original post.

Comment: Looks fine to me. `callback` clearly never returns a nil map. Next you could try adding some logging to be sure the right function is being called, or see if there's anything interesting in the stacktrace (probably not, alas).